# Google Analytics API - filter dimension sourceMedium

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to filter certain sources and mediums (specifically email clients). I need to keep the dimension as one column (I use the maximum number of dimensions - 7).

The filter works fine when I have only one sourceMedium such as:

```
ga:sourceMedium!=amail.centrum.cz / referral
```

Filter doesn’t work at all when I use two sourceMedium:

```
ga:sourceMedium!=amail.centrum.cz / referral,ga:sourceMedium!=mail.google.com / referral
```

It doesn’t matter If I use AND / OR, the query doesn’t output the desired data.

I assume that there supposed to be some delimiter which could identify that `amail.centrum.cz` is one string which is delimited by another one. I already tried to use `'` at the beginning and at the end of the string, but it seems that it doesn’t work.

Is there anything that I missed in docs or anything else? Looking for your help :)

BTW: I'm aware of the solution: Pull out data from GA, filter data manually (compare output data vs my list of email clients what I would like to exclude)

Comment: I would suggest using the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AsourceMedium&filters=ga%3AsourceMedium!%3DGmail.com%20%2F%20Publicidad%20email%2Cga%3AsourceMedium!%3Danalytics.corp.google.com%20%2F%20referral) to get your query formatted correctly. Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "the query doesn’t output the desired data."? Keep in mind that your request should be url encoded `&filters=ga%3AsourceMedium!%3DGmail.com%20%2F%20Publicidad%20email%2Cga%3AsourceMedium!%3Danalytics.corp.google.com%20%2F%20referral`

Comment: Hmm, I’ve changed the log operand to AND `;` and the query filtered the mentioned sourceMedium -> my desired data was filtered data without mentioned sourceMediums = I get to my "desired data" :-). Maybe I am too stupid, but when I put AND between this two sourceMedium it means that they need to be there both (but in this case it is not true all the time - I could have some sources which are mentioned in filter, but not in input data - there is nothing to filter) and on the other hand, there is OR which suits my use-case very good. Or am I trapped in logic? Btw thank you for a fast reply.